# DexPathList issue

Tags: android, classnotfoundexception

I have had this problem a lot and I don't know what to do to solve it, it appears and disappear randomly!

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application **class name**: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "Package name" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~d8jgfjeVQjtH0tNW5s9DGA==/com.emeint.android.myservices-cghszmsbfN2eJgSRSBhZDg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~d8jgfjeVQjtH0tNW5s9DGA==/com.emeint.android.myservices-cghszmsbfN2eJgSRSBhZDg==/lib/arm64, /data/app/~~d8jgfjeVQjtH0tNW5s9DGA==/com.emeint.android.myservices-cghszmsbfN2eJgSRSBhZDg==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/system_ext/lib64]]
    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:1332)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleMakeApplication(ActivityThread.java:7469)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:7440)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:301)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2148)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8506)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
```

What is this problem ? I tried many solutions and I don't know what the problem is to solve or what I should look for.
So can anyone help me?

Thank you.

Comment: have you found a solution?